# Is it possible to connect to a websocket on the same server using Flask?

Tags: python, flask, websocket

I'm trying to make a minimal implementation of an API that responds to a POST request by connecting to a websocket on the same server, using `Flask`, `websocket-client`, and `flask-sock`

Here is the code:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sock import Sock
import websocket

app = Flask(__name__)
sock = Sock(app)

@sock.route('/echo')
def echo(ws):
    while True:
        data = ws.receive()
        print(data)
        ws.send(data)

@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def hello_world():
    ws = websocket.WebSocket()
    ws.connect(f'ws://localhost:5000/echo')
    ws.send('hello')
    resp = ws.recv()
    ws.close()
    return resp

sock.app.run()
```

when I send a POST request to `http://localhost:5000/`, I get a 307 Temporary Redirect error.

I've also tried:

1. running the app through ngrok, where I've tried every combination of sending the POST request to `localhost`/the ngrok URL and making the websocket URL `localhost`/the ngrok URL
2. running two separate tunnels with ngrok - one for the HTTP server and another as a dedicated websocket server (moving the `echo` function and all relevant code over

none of these approaches has worked

**Is it possible to connect to a websocket in this way using Python (or at all?)** Thank you!

Comment: There's no inherent reason why you can't connect to a websocket on the same server. This sounds like an issue with the webserver configuration. It may be using name-based virtual hosting, and doesn't recognize the name `localhost`.

Comment: Where is it redirecting you to?